# Why are MySQL columns case-insensitive?

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions, conventions

In MySQL, table names are case-sensitive but column names aren't.

What's the  **reason** for this decision?

Isn't it better to stick to one convention for both?

Comment: I know that you just recently "registered" this account, and wanted the one on dba.se registered as well, but that didn't take. Can you register the one over there as well, or create an account over there?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Some storage engines use one or more files for a table, with as filename the tablename.

Certain operating systems (Windows) are case-insensitive for files, and others (unix) are case-sensitive.

Set the [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) variable different from 0 to disable case sensitivity, and read more about [Identifier case sensitivity here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: Couldn't MySQL have stored that information within the file itself instead of relying on differing OS naming conventions?

Comment: Sure, a storage engine can manage its tables as it prefers. One big file, one file per table, with filename=tablename or not... if you can code, you might even be able to help :)